# Bash: Email not firing

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a requirement where I need to test is `ssh tunnel` is alive or not from different server. 
This is how code looks like to check if the connection is live, if it is alive, it would send email.

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVERIP=192.xxx.xxx.xxx
NOTIFYEMAIL=xyz@gmail.com
SENDEREMAIL=alert@localhost
SERVER=http://127.0.0.1/

ping -c 3 $SERVERIP > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
# Use your favorite mailer here:
mailx -s "Server $SERVERIP is down" -r "$SENDEREMAIL" -t  "$NOTIFYEMAIL" </dev/null 
fi
```

However, on running this ssh file, the below error is generated. can someone help me out.

> No recipients specified
>   "/home/user name/dead.letter" 10/303

Comment: the -t switch force you to have a specific header format. Remove it and see it it works better

Comment: thanks, it worked.

Comment: So I'll put it as an answer

Comment: As an aside, the construct `cmd; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then stuff; fi` is better written `if cmd; then stuff; fi` or even simply `cmd && stuff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the -t switch force you to have a specific header format. Remove it and it will works better